# Using switch in Java but not sure why it works

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I was trying to implement an option when my program starts to either enter the admin side or the storefront side. When I added using switch and case at the start of my program it worked right away but I don't know why. When I enter option 2 to go to the store front it enters and I thought I would need to make a method for it to enter the store front.

Can someone explain what is exactly happening at the beginning of my code? I think I just happened to get lucky.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Login to Admin site (1) or go to store front (2)?");
            
                int choice = scnr.nextInt();
                
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
                    server.start(6666);
                
                case 2:
                    
                }
                
        inventoryManager.initializeInventoryFromFile("inventory.json");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Game Store \n");
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("************MAIN MENU ******************\n");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter one of the following:\n\n" + "'1' : View Products\n" + "'2' : Purchase Products\n"
                    + "'3' : Return Products\n" + "'4' : Exit");

            int menuChoice = scnr.nextInt();

            switch (menuChoice) {
            case 1:
                viewProducts();
                break;
            case 2:
                purchaseProducts();
                break;
            case 3:
                returnProducts();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Thank you for coming by. Please come again.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("INVALID OPTION. Please select an option 1-4");
                scnr.close();
            } 
    //      server.cleanUp();
        }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding & at beginning?

Comment: @JustaNobody I guess OP means running in background

Comment: @Mitchell you should be providing reproduction steps. The question doesn't show where and how did you use `&`.

Comment: I apologize everyone, I tried to italicize my words and it didn't work. I will edit my description to make it more clear. My fault.

Comment: Wait do you only need to execute the code below case 2 only if input is 2?

Comment: @JustaNobody yes that is correct. case 1 is still being developed that is supposed to be the admin page. case 2 will then go down so that code below it can then be executed and go through the different prompts in the store.

Comment: @Mitchell don't take those personally. I got those too at beginning. Just learn to better phrase the questions using the sites formatting.

Comment: @JustaNobody thank you for the advice. I will keep plugging away. I do find that most difficult is how to work my questions and also just even googling the right words/phrases to get the answer I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first switch terminates before the execution of code below. If you want `case 2` to run below code then the code must be in the `body` of `case 2`.
add `break` before ending of `case 1` to make sure `case 2` does not run.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Login to Admin site (1) or go to store front (2)?");
            
                int choice = scnr.nextInt();
                
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
                    server.start(6666);
                  break; //stops execution here
  
                case 2:
                    
                //} //don't close switch here
                
        inventoryManager.initializeInventoryFromFile("inventory.json");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Game Store \n");
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu");
        System.out.println("***************************************");
        System.out.println("************MAIN MENU ******************\n");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter one of the following:\n\n" + "'1' : View Products\n" + "'2' : Purchase Products\n"
                    + "'3' : Return Products\n" + "'4' : Exit");

            int menuChoice = scnr.nextInt();

            switch (menuChoice) {
            case 1:
                viewProducts();
                break;
            case 2:
                purchaseProducts();
                break;
            case 3:
                returnProducts();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Thank you for coming by. Please come again.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("INVALID OPTION. Please select an option 1-4");
                scnr.close();
            } 
    //      server.cleanUp();
    }//close switch here
        }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... When I enter option 2 to go to the store front it enters and I thought I would need to make a method for it to enter the store front. ..."*
>
> *"... Can someone explain what is exactly happening at the beginning of my code? I think I just happened to get lucky."*

No luck, that's how the *[switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)*  structure will function.

It's an optimized equivalent of multiple *[if-else](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)* statements.

The following two structures are equivalent, in terms of *[control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)*.
Note the *break* keyword.

```java
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
        server.start(6666);
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
}

if (choice == 1) {
    StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
    server.start(6666);
} else if (choice == 2) {

}
```

Essentially, your second branch, *case 2*, has no attributing statements, so nothing is executed, and the *switch* is exited.

> *"... is there a better way I could implement this? Would my way be "buggy" in a sense?"*

It might be viewed as *"buggy"* since the branches don't require brackets, and forgetting to add the *break* keyword can cause the code to conflict.

It's a very old syntax, abstracted from the C programming language.
Similar to *labels*, which Java recommends to avoid unless necessary.

Here is an example of the newer *switch* structure, which has a slightly different syntax.

Instead of the *colon*, *:*, you use *->*.  And, a break is inferred.

```java
switch (choice) {
    case 1 -> {
        StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
        server.start(6666);
    }
    case 2 -> { }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that up! So I guess did I do it properly or is there a better way I could implement this? Would my way be "buggy" in a sense?

Comment: @Mitchell be aware that your code is more like `if (choice == 1) { StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0); server.start(6666); } if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {  } /* do the rest */` - posted code has no `break;` so there is no `else` functionality, `case 1` is falling through to `case 2` (it is empty anyways)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I modified the answer.

Comment: @Mitchell, there are two different syntax's for _switch_ structures.  The newer one, added in _Java 12_, infers a _break_, so you don't have to write it every time.  I'll add a basic example to my answer.

Comment: @Mitchell, I've updated the answer to include an answer and example.

Comment: @Reilas thank you for that, great solution but I didn't clarify that we use Java 11 so this solution could not be implemented into my program as this is used in Java 14 forward.

Comment: @Mitchell, no problem, glad it helped.  I would recommend utilizing a bracketed scope for each branch, this may reduce a chance for bugs, as it defines separation from each case.  And, just try to make practice by adding the break keywords.

Comment: @Reilas thank you for that I really do appreciate your help, very insightful. When your saying for each branch are you meaning brackets after each case statement?

Comment: @Mitchell, correct, they are optional.  This can sometimes improve the readability, which can help prevent creating bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your example that I can see is this part:

```
switch (choice) {
       case 1:
            StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
            server.start(6666);
                
       case 2:
}
```

After case 1 is executed, it "falls thru" to case 2 (which has yet to be defined).  You should use a `break` after each case unless you want them to fall thru.

The above is the equivalent of

```
if(choice == 1) {
     StoreFront server = new StoreFront(0);
     server.start(6666);
}
// now execute what case 2 would do
```

And don't forget the [*switch expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

```
for (int choice : new int[]{2,4}) {
    int result = switch (choice) {
        case 1, 2, 3 -> 5; // returns 5 for 1,2, or 3
        case 4, 5, 6 -> {  // similar for 4,5,or 6
            System.out.println("returning 6");
            yield 6;
        }
        default -> 1;
    };
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

prints

```
result = 5
returning 6
result = 6
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was a quick guess.